# ImageGrid - set_ylabel cut off by figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot some figures and have the title for each row positioned on the left. The issue I face with using ImageGrid is that the title is cut off by the next figure as shown below.

[image]

```
for idx in range(0,1):
    fig  = plt.figure(idx, (15, 10))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 10), axes_pad=0.1, share_all=True)  

    # disable ticks
    grid[0].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    grid[0].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

    # labels
    grid[0].set_ylabel("Input", fontsize=20, rotation=0)
    grid[10].set_ylabel("Ground Truth", fontsize=20, rotation=0)
    grid[20].set_ylabel("Prediction", fontsize=20, rotation=0)

    # images
    for j in range(10):
        grid[j].imshow(x_true[idx,j], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+10].imshow(x_true[idx,j+10], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+20].imshow(x_temp[idx,j], cmap="gray")
```

I was using subplots before this (see [Subplots not aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514288/subplots-not-aligned)) and had the same issue as well. I have gone through a number of threads and solutions but none them have worked, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution finally. To use the `labelpad` argument in `set_ylabel`. [How to print Y axis label horizontally in a matplotlib / pylab chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671748/how-to-print-y-axis-label-horizontally-in-a-matplotlib-pylab-chart)